# Getting the Average (?) of data from literature review

Tags: mean, systematic-review

I have reviewed many literature, and extracted their data.  I wanted to get the average of the values of each property.  Say, I have 50 journal articles which reported the metal composition (as % composition) (of Gold, Copper and Lead) of e-wastes.  How do I calculate the average % composition of Gold (or Copper or Lead) from all the data from the 50 journal articles?

Is this also a meta analysis?  Thanks!

Comment: I think it is meta analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a meta-analysis. For synthesizing a percent or proportion, I recommend using the natural log of the logit along as the effect size, along with its standard error:
$$ES_{ln(logit)} = ln\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$$
and
$$ SE_{ES} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{np}+\frac{1}{n(1-p)}}$$ .
Then apply standard meta-analytic methods to determine the mean and related statistics. You can then transform the results back into proportions using
$$ p = \frac{e^{ln(logit)}}{e^{ln(logit)}+1} $$

Comment: dbwilson..how about if the data are not % compositions? say exact measurements (i.e. weight, length)?

Comment: You can still meta-analyze those data. You just need the standard error so that you can compute the inverse variance weight.